# Unable to update JDK 7

Tags: update-manager, jdk

I've installed JDK through the Webupd8 PPA (`oracle-java7-installer`).

The problem is that whenever I try to update Java, the process just pauses after connecting with Oracle's server. If I force close the terminal, then I can't update anything because of the incomplete Java update.

[image]

Comment: Have you had this problem for some time? It could just be something broken with the oracle servers right now.

Comment: Image is not working can you reupload and paste it

Comment: updated the image

Comment: @MagnusJonsson no .this problem always arises whenever theres a new update available for jdk